# Azure VM managent and metrics role

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, rbac

Is there a **one built-in role** that allows a user to do **only** the following:

1. Start , restart and stop VM.
2. Display VM metrics to this user.

Metrics such as CPU and RAM utilization.

It seems like it requires both "virtual machine administrator login"
role and "monitoring reader" role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such a role, but you can easily create one.

```
"Microsoft.Compute/*/read"
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action"
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action"
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action"
```

these are the actions required. you can obviously be a little bit more hardcore with read permissions